# Proof that the shape operator is a self adjoint application

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that the shape operator in the first fundamental form is self adjoint. I have an application $\mathbb{X}: (u,v) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ which determines a base of the tangent plane in a point $P$ of my surface, given by $\{ \mathbb{X}_u \mathbb{X}_v \}$, so I just have to proof that $\mathcal{F}_p(w_1) \cdot w_2 = w_1 \cdot \mathcal{F}_p(w_2)$ for $w_1, w_2$ being all the possible combinations between $\mathbb{X}_u, \mathbb{X}_v$. I am having trouble when $w_1 = \mathbb{X}_u$ and $w_2 = \mathbb{X}_v$, where:
$$\mathcal{F}_p(\mathbb{X}_u)\cdot \mathbb{X}_v=-N_u\cdot \mathbb{X}_v=-\mathbb{X}_u \cdot N_v = \mathbb{X}_u \cdot \mathcal{F}_p(\mathbb{X}_v)$$
I don't understand why the second equality is true. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Ben123's comments, I realized that my answer needs to be edited. I will explain things better this time.

Let $\overline{M}$ be a (semi-)Riemannian manifold, with metric denoted by $\bar{g}$ and let $M$ be a submanifold of $\overline{M}$, with induced metric denoted by $g$. We denote by $\overline{\nabla}$ and $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connections on $\overline{M}$ and $M$ respectively. By definition, a Levi-Civita connection is torsion-free and compatible with the metric. Its existence and uniqueness is a theorem (which is sometimes known as the fundamental theorem of differential geometry).

Given a point $p \in M$, we note that the tangent space $T_p(\overline{M})$ of $\overline{M}$ at $p$ decomposes as:
$$ T_p(\overline{M}) \simeq T_p(M) \oplus N_p, $$
(an orthogonal decomposition with respect to $\bar{g}_p$) using the inner product $\bar{g}_p$, where $T_p(M)$ denotes the tangent space of $M$ at $p$ and $N_p$ denotes the fiber of the normal bundle $N$ of $M$ as a submanifold of $\overline{M}$.

Given $X$, $Y \in T_p(M)$, we extend them to some local vector fields in some neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $\overline{M}$, which are tangent to $M$ at $U \cap M$, we define
$$ \Pi_p(X, Y) = \overline{\nabla}_X(Y)^\perp $$
to be the orthogonal (with respect to $\bar{g}$) projection of $\overline{\nabla}_X(Y)$ onto the fiber $N_p$ of the normal bundle.
$\Pi(-,-)$ is called the second fundamental form. It is well defined as a local smooth section of $T^*(M) \otimes T^*(M) \otimes N$. In other words, the second fundamental form does not depend on the choices of extensions of $X$ and $Y$.

Also, given $X$ and $Y \in T_p(M)$ and $\xi \in N_p$, we define the shape operator $S_p^\xi \in End(T_p(M))$ by
$$ g_p(S_p^\xi(X), Y) = \bar{g}_p(\Pi_p(X, Y), \xi). $$

Note that we have
$$ g_p(S_p^\xi(X), Y) = \bar{g}_p(\overline{\nabla}_X(Y), \xi) = \bar{g}_p(\overline{\nabla}_Y(X) + [X, Y], \xi),$$
using the fact that $\overline{\nabla}$ is torsion-free. But $[X, Y] \in T_p(M)$, so it is orthogonal to $\xi$ (with respect to $\bar{g}_p$). We thus get
$$ g_p(S_p^\xi(X), Y) = \bar{g}_p(\overline{\nabla}_Y(X), \xi) = g_p(X, S^\xi_p(Y)),$$
so that $S^\xi_p$ is indeed self-adjoint with respect to $g_p$.

Comment: From what I know, the second fundamental form is defined by the mapping $$(X,Y) \mapsto (\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y)^{\perp}$$ where $$\overline{\nabla}$$ is the unique covariant derivative (metric and torsion-free connection) on a semi-riemannian manifold $(\overline{M},\overline{g})$. The Weingarten map/Shape operator is implicitly defined by the equation $$\overline{g}(\Pi(X,Y),\xi) = g(S^{\xi}(X),Y)$$ where $\xi \in \mathfrak{X}(M)^{\perp}$ is a normal field, and where $(M,g)$ is a semi-riemannian submanifold of $(\overline{M},\overline{g})$. Is this def. compatible with yours?

Comment: And we also have, in connection (connection in the "ordinary" sense) with the above, $$(\overline{\nabla}_{X}\xi)^{\top} = -S^{\xi}(X)$$ for normal fields $\xi \in \mathfrak{X}(M)^{\perp}$ and $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ where $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ denotes all smooth vector fields on a smooth manifold $M$.

Comment: @Ben123, I have edited my answer in light of your comments. Indeed, my answer definitely needed editing. Thank you.

Comment: Looks good. I suppose you use that the metric is symmetric in the last step, maybe it is to obvious to be spelled out but. I actually realize why it is self-adjoint now, so thanks for your explanation (using the Lie-bracket/commutator of $X,Y$ in that one step).

Also, is there a particular reason why you limit yourself to looking at points $p \in M$? The notation get's a bit more cumbersome. I suppose you could also just look at smooth vector fields over $M$, i.e. $X,Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$?

Comment: @Ben123, yes, I have used that the metric is symmetric in the last step. Also, you are right in that differentiating a vector in a certain direction doesn't really make sense. One can though differentiate a vector field. I will edit again later today to make it clearer.

Comment: @Ben123, I added some more remarks. I hope it is clearer now. It is still not perfectly well written, but I hope it is clear. It is a proposition that the second fundamental form does not depend on choices of extensions of the vectors to locally defined vector fields (while respecting tangentiality/ normality to $M$).